# Specific Block Data?

Tags: blocks, chaindata, data

How can I get data from a specific block in the past? Does node providers support archive node? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need access to the archive node if you're trying to get the block data from a historical archival block. But if you need some information to replay the state of the chain at that particular block in the past, then you need an archive node. That being said QuickNode provides both full and full-archive data.

With QuickNode, you get the following:

- Free forever plan.
- Archival data on all the plans, even the free plan.
- [Fastest Ethereum provider](https://blog.quicknode.com/justifying-quick-in-quicknode-response-time-comparison-of-various-blockchain-node-providers/)

That being said, here's an example of running `[eth_getBlockTransactionCountByNumber][2]` with ethers v6:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
(async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("QUICKNODE_HTTP_URL");
  const txCount = await provider.send("eth_getBlockTransactionCountByNumber", [
    "0xc5043f",
  ]);
  console.log(txCount);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://console.chainstack.com/user/account/create) here.

You don't really need an archive node if you only need the block information using a method like `eth_getBlockByNumber`, for example.

Here is an example using `web3.js` and `eth_getBlockByNumber`:

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const NODE_URL = "CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

async function getBlock(blockNumber) {
    const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber, false);
    console.log(block);
  }
  
getBlock(16591600)
```

> You can find more information and examples using this method on [eth_getBlockByNumber docs](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-getblockbynumber).

These are the methods requiring an archive node:

- [eth_getBalance](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-getbalance)
- [eth_getCode](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-getcode)
- [eth_getTransactionCount](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-gettransactioncount)
- [eth_getStorageAt](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-getstorageat)
- [eth_call](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-ethcall)

You can get a full node with Chainstack for free if you need one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Alchemy provides access to the archive node(at least you can call the block data of any block, not sure about traces and all) but I would recommend doing your own research as they have different plans according to the number of requests

other providers may also provide access to the archive node

Answer (score 0):

Using ethers you can just use the function getBlock if you have a provider. Example:

```
await provider.getBlock(100004)
// {
//   _difficulty: { BigNumber: "3849295379889" },
//   difficulty: 3849295379889,
//   extraData: '0x476574682f76312e302e312d39383130306634372f6c696e75782f676f312e34',
//   gasLimit: { BigNumber: "3141592" },
//   gasUsed: { BigNumber: "21000" },
//   hash: '0xf93283571ae16dcecbe1816adc126954a739350cd1523a1559eabeae155fbb63',
//   miner: '0x909755D480A27911cB7EeeB5edB918fae50883c0',
//   nonce: '0x1a455280001cc3f8',
//   number: 100004,
//   parentHash: '0x73d88d376f6b4d232d70dc950d9515fad3b5aa241937e362fdbfd74d1c901781',
//   timestamp: 1439799168,
//   transactions: [
//     '0x6f12399cc2cb42bed5b267899b08a847552e8c42a64f5eb128c1bcbd1974fb0c'
//   ]
// }
```

If you want all the transaction data you can use getBlockWithTransactions:

```
await provider.getBlockWithTransactions(100004)
// {
//   _difficulty: { BigNumber: "3849295379889" },
//   difficulty: 3849295379889,
//   extraData: '0x476574682f76312e302e312d39383130306634372f6c696e75782f676f312e34',
//   gasLimit: { BigNumber: "3141592" },
//   gasUsed: { BigNumber: "21000" },
//   hash: '0xf93283571ae16dcecbe1816adc126954a739350cd1523a1559eabeae155fbb63',
//   miner: '0x909755D480A27911cB7EeeB5edB918fae50883c0',
//   nonce: '0x1a455280001cc3f8',
//   number: 100004,
//   parentHash: '0x73d88d376f6b4d232d70dc950d9515fad3b5aa241937e362fdbfd74d1c901781',
//   timestamp: 1439799168,
//   transactions: [
//     {
//       accessList: null,
//       blockHash: '0xf93283571ae16dcecbe1816adc126954a739350cd1523a1559eabeae155fbb63',
//       blockNumber: 100004,
//       chainId: 0,
//       confirmations: 16887683,
//       creates: null,
//       data: '0x',
//       from: '0xcf00A85f3826941e7A25BFcF9Aac575d40410852',
//       gasLimit: { BigNumber: "90000" },
//       gasPrice: { BigNumber: "54588778004" },
//       hash: '0x6f12399cc2cb42bed5b267899b08a847552e8c42a64f5eb128c1bcbd1974fb0c',
//       nonce: 25,
//       r: '0xb23adc880d3735e4389698dddc953fb02f1fa9b57e84d3510a2a4b3597ac2486',
//       s: '0x4e856f95c4e2828933246fb4765a5bfd2ca5959840643bef0e80b4e3a243d064',
//       to: '0xD9666150A9dA92d9108198a4072970805a8B3428',
//       transactionIndex: 0,
//       type: 0,
//       v: 27,
//       value: { BigNumber: "5000000000000000000" },
//       wait: [Function (anonymous)]
//     }
//   ]
// }
```